# Firebase analytics are not logging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

we are using firebase to log our user events. some of the events are getting logged in the dashboard but most of the events are not getting logged . It is very hard to believe that "No user performed these events", because we have more than 500K users and these events are very basic.

We are also using google analytics, where all expected events are being logged.

Please suggest how to analyze it.

```
/**
 * This method will log the events in firebase console
 * @param itemId
 * @param itemName
 * @param screen
 */
public  void logFirebaseCustomEvent(String event,String itemId,String itemName,String screen){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, itemId);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, itemName);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, screen);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(event, bundle);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please add your code for working & not working events

Comment: This is single method being used for all the events. Thats the more painful thing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason with the help of debug view(https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview). I was sending invalid event name.

Now it is working fine. :) :)

Comment: How can an event name be invalid? My understanding was that event name can be any string, is that incorrect?

Comment: fyi Firebase Analytics expects all Event names in lowercase, with underscores instead of spaces: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event (also for Param names).

Answer (score 1):

Please check your manifest file whether you are using a meta tag for firebase analytics value is "true" or "false".

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP comment answer refers to being wrong to enter the package name, and not the event name in ADB command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app **package_name**
```